# microsoft excel Excel alphabetical index

Tags: algorithms

I would like if someone can give me the numerical indices of the Microsoft Excel alphabetical indices.

It Is as follows:  $A$ is $1$ and $Z$ is $26$ then the indices starts from $AA=27$, $AB=28$ to $ZZ$ and then from $AAA$ to $ZZZ$. Given an index like $AGVYD$, how can I calculate its numerical Index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to think about the labeling system is as a new number system.  This number system is base-26, and each 'digit' is replaced by a letter.

In base-ten, the number '123' means:

$$1*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 3*10^0$$

In our new excel-version base-26 'ABCD' means:

$$(A=1)*26^3 + (B=2)*26^2 + (C=3)*26^1 + (D=4)*26^0$$

Comment: \cdot to get $\cdot$

Comment: Note that this is a somewhat weird version of base-26, since it lacks a digit for 0 but does have a digit (Z) with the value 26. Still, your decoding formula does work.